# Python code to find difference between two dates

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, datetime

I have been working on porting my PowerShell 7 scripts to Python 3.9.5 lately, re-implementing the same logic in a different programming language, keeping what makes it work and removing unnecessary parts, improving the code, and this is one of the scripts that has been re-implemented.

The code is simple, and I know this has been implemented countless times, but it does get the job done without using the builtin `datetime` module, and it accepts two strings representing dates in  nine date formats and returns the difference between the two dates:

```Python
'yyyy-MM-dd'
'yyyy/MM/dd'
'MM/dd/yyyy'
'MMM dd, yyyy'
'dd MMM, yyyy'
'MMMM dd, yyyy'
'dd MMMM, yyyy'
'yyyy, MMM dd'
'yyyy, MMMM dd'
```

And it is completely working.

So here is the code:

```Python
import re
import sys

Months = (
    {'Month':'January', 'Days':31},
    {'Month':'February', 'Days':28},
    {'Month':'March', 'Days':31},
    {'Month':'April', 'Days':30},
    {'Month':'May', 'Days':31},
    {'Month':'June', 'Days':30},
    {'Month':'July', 'Days':31},
    {'Month':'August', 'Days':31},
    {'Month':'September', 'Days':30},
    {'Month':'October', 'Days':31},
    {'Month':'November', 'Days':30},
    {'Month':'December', 'Days':31}
)

Culture = (
    {'Format':'yyyy-MM-dd', 'Regex':'^\d{4}\-0?([2-9]|1[0-2]?)\-(0?(3[01]|[12][0-9]|[1-9]))$'},
    {'Format':'yyyy/MM/dd', 'Regex':'^\d{4}\/0?([2-9]|1[0-2]?)\/(0?(3[01]|[12][0-9]|[1-9]))$'},
    {'Format':'MM/dd/yyyy', 'Regex':'^0?([2-9]|1[0-2]?)\/(0?(3[01]|[12][0-9]|[1-9]))\/\d{4}$'},
    {'Format':'MMM dd, yyyy', 'Regex':'^[A-Za-z]{3} (0?(3[01]|[12][0-9]|[1-9])), \d{4}$'},
    {'Format':'dd MMM, yyyy', 'Regex':'^(0?(3[01]|[12][0-9]|[1-9])) [A-Za-z]{3}, \d{4}$'},
    {'Format':'MMMM dd, yyyy', 'Regex':'^[A-Za-z]{3,9} (0?(3[01]|[12][0-9]|[1-9])), \d{4}$'},
    {'Format':'dd MMMM, yyyy', 'Regex':'^(0?(3[01]|[12][0-9]|[1-9])) [A-Za-z]{3,9}, \d{4}$'},
    {'Format':'yyyy, MMM dd', 'Regex':'^\d{4}, [A-Za-z]{3} (0?(3[01]|[12][0-9]|[1-9]))$'},
    {'Format':'yyyy, MMMM dd', 'Regex':'^\d{4}, [A-Za-z]{3,9} (0?(3[01]|[12][0-9]|[1-9]))$'}
)

def splitter(date, x, y):
    date = date.replace(',','').split(x)
    y = list(map(int, y.split(',')))
    year = int(date[y[0]])
    month = date[y[1]]
    if not re.match('^\d+$', month):
        for i in Months:
            if re.match(f'{month}',i['Month']): month = Months.index(i) + 1
    month = int(month)
    day = int(date[y[2]])
    return {'Year': year, 'Month': month, 'Day': day}

def parsedate(date):
    for a in range(len(Culture)):
        if re.match('%s' % Culture[a]['Regex'], date): i = a; break
    if i == 0: return splitter(date, '-', '0,1,2')
    elif i == 1: return splitter(date, '/', '0,1,2')
    elif i == 2: return splitter(date, '/', '2,0,1')
    elif i == 3: return splitter(date, ' ', '2,0,1')
    elif i == 4: return splitter(date, ' ', '2,1,0')
    elif i == 5: return splitter(date, ' ', '2,0,1')
    elif i == 6: return splitter(date, ' ', '2,1,0')
    elif i == 7: return splitter(date, ' ', '0,1,2')
    elif i == 8: return splitter(date, ' ', '0,1,2')

def totaldays(date):
    ye = date['Year']
    y = ye
    mon = date['Month']
    d = date['Day']
    if mon <= 2: y -= 1
    leaps = y // 4 - y // 100 + y // 400
    m = 0
    for b in range(mon - 1): m += int(Months[b].get('Days'))
    days = (ye - 1) * 365 + m + d + leaps
    return days

def diffdate(start, end):
    date1 = totaldays(parsedate(start))
    date2 = totaldays(parsedate(end))
    ddate = date2 - date1
    print(ddate)

start = sys.argv[1]
end = sys.argv[2]
diffdate(start, end)
```

As usual, I wonder how it can be improved, there may be multiple areas that can be improved but now I mostly care about the switch replacement and how to get parameters from command line, the 8 elif statements do the job but it makes the code look awful, I have tried to use a dictionary but it throws date is undefined error, and I don't want to import sys just to get the arguments from command line, I don't know if there is an automatic variable just like PowerShell's `$Args`.

Please help me improve my code, you can share whatever you think on my code.

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result or https://youtu.be/-5wpm-gesOY? While useful for learning, dates can be notoriously difficult to get right. Therefore for any type of "serious" application, it is strongly recommended to use the `datetime` libraries =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modern Python has so many conveniences for creating simple data objects
(namedtuple, dataclass, and the excellent [attrs](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/index.html) library), that it's usually a
mistake to structure your internal data using ordinary dicts, lists, or tuples.
These simple data objects not only clean up the code from a readability
perspective (as shown in multiple places below) but also encourage you to focus
your attention where it should be: defining the meaningful data entities to
facilitate and support the algorithmic needs of the program. Organize the data
the right way, and the algorithms will usually flow naturally.

Case in point: you don't need an 8-way switch; you need richer data. The
`splitter()` arguments belong in the realm of data (`Culture` instances in the
code below), not algorithm.

Another case in point: don't drive your algorithm with data that requires
parsing. For example, if you think you need a tuple of indexes like `(2, 0, 1)`, don't store it in a comma-delimited string and complicate your algorithmic
code with the unpacking logic. Just store the indexes directly as a tuple of
integers. The core problem in software writing is reducing and managing
complexity, and the greatest complexity is always algorithmic.
Investing more in creating "smarter" or "richer" data will help you keep the
algorithmic parts of the code easier to understand and maintain.

Python has a built-in `sum()` function.

When possible (which means almost always) iterate directly
over a collection (ie, list, tuple) rather than over the indexes.
If you need the indexes too, use `enumerate()`.

Abandon your style of trying to cram extra logic on each line:

```
if foo > 1233: x = 12; y = 34
```

I went through that phase for a brief time early in my Python journey. It
doesn't scale well and it's harder to maintain over the long term on a project.
Again, complexity is the biggest foe in software engineering: one way to
reducing complexity slightly (and increase readability) is to favor shorter
lines of code over longer ones. Within reason, taller/skinnier texts are easier
on readers than shorter/wider texts (the publishing industry has understood
this for decades), so if you are cramming more code into single lines, you are
economizing on the wrong thing (ie, saving lines while spending readability).

Similarly, abandon your aversion to importing parts of the Python standard
library. It's fine to avoid those things in the name of learning. But that's
the only good reason I know of. So get command-line arguments from `sys.argv`
guilt-free. It's the way to go!

After the simplification from those changes are made, the `splitter()` function
seems unnecessary. Instead, I would suggest a different helper function just to
parse the month. And that logic doesn't require regex: you can use simpler
things like `isdigit()` and `startswith()`. Also, a `Month` should know its
number. Again, use richer data to simplify algorithm.

Other improvements for you to consider:

- If you invest more in your regular expressions so that they use named
  captures, you can drop the tedious details in `Culture.separator` and
  `Culture.indexes`. Instead, you can grab the year, month, and day directly from
  the `re.Match` object, by name. Yet again, **smart data, simple code**.
- When given invalid input, your code just blows up. Give some thought to
  whether you want to invest in better error handling/reporting.
- Dates are notoriously complicated. There are probably weird edge-case
  bugs in your code. Are you sure you don't want to use `datetime`?

```python
import re
import sys
from collections import namedtuple

# Simple data objects are handy as hell. Use more of them.

Month = namedtuple('Month', 'name number days')
Culture = namedtuple('Culture', 'format separator indexes regex')
Date = namedtuple('Date', 'year month day')

Months = (
    Month('January', 1, 31),
    Month('February', 2, 28),
    Month('March', 3, 31),
    Month('April', 4, 30),
    Month('May', 5, 31),
    Month('June', 6, 30),
    Month('July', 7, 31),
    Month('August', 8, 31),
    Month('September', 9, 30),
    Month('October', 10, 31),
    Month('November', 11, 30),
    Month('December', 12, 31),
)

Cultures = (
    Culture('yyyy-MM-dd',    '-', (0,1,2), '^\d{4}\-0?([2-9]|1[0-2]?)\-(0?(3[01]|[12][0-9]|[1-9]))$'),
    Culture('yyyy/MM/dd',    '/', (0,1,2), '^\d{4}\/0?([2-9]|1[0-2]?)\/(0?(3[01]|[12][0-9]|[1-9]))$'),
    Culture('MM/dd/yyyy',    '/', (2,0,1), '^0?([2-9]|1[0-2]?)\/(0?(3[01]|[12][0-9]|[1-9]))\/\d{4}$'),
    Culture('MMM dd, yyyy',  ' ', (2,0,1), '^[A-Za-z]{3} (0?(3[01]|[12][0-9]|[1-9])), \d{4}$'),
    Culture('dd MMM, yyyy',  ' ', (2,1,0), '^(0?(3[01]|[12][0-9]|[1-9])) [A-Za-z]{3}, \d{4}$'),
    Culture('MMMM dd, yyyy', ' ', (2,0,1), '^[A-Za-z]{3,9} (0?(3[01]|[12][0-9]|[1-9])), \d{4}$'),
    Culture('dd MMMM, yyyy', ' ', (2,1,0), '^(0?(3[01]|[12][0-9]|[1-9])) [A-Za-z]{3,9}, \d{4}$'),
    Culture('yyyy, MMM dd',  ' ', (0,1,2), '^\d{4}, [A-Za-z]{3} (0?(3[01]|[12][0-9]|[1-9]))$'),
    Culture('yyyy, MMMM dd', ' ', (0,1,2), '^\d{4}, [A-Za-z]{3,9} (0?(3[01]|[12][0-9]|[1-9]))$'),
)

# A purely stylistic point: organize modules the way you want to read them.
# Most humans like to read things top to bottom.

def main(args):
    start, end = args
    ddate = diffdate(start, end)
    print(ddate)

def diffdate(start, end):
    d1 = totaldays(parsedate(start))
    d2 = totaldays(parsedate(end))
    return d2 - d1

def totaldays(date):
    y = date.year
    if date.month <= 2:
        y -= 1
    leaps = y // 4 - y // 100 + y // 400
    m = sum(Months[b].days for b in range(date.month - 1))
    days = (date.year - 1) * 365 + m + date.day + leaps
    return days

def parsedate(date):
    for c in Cultures:
        if re.match(c.regex, date):
            parts = date.replace(',', '').split(c.separator)
            return Date(
                int(parts[c.indexes[0]]),
                parsemonth(parts[c.indexes[1]]),
                int(parts[c.indexes[2]]),
            )
    # Raise an error if we get here.

def parsemonth(month):
    if month.isdigit():
        return int(month)
    else:
        for m in Months:
            if m.name.lower().startswith(month.lower()):
                return m.number
    # Raise an error if we get here.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a good approach you have done if you have to skip `datetime` module.

There are many more cultures that you have not added but that's different topic.

First, I will answer your question related to command line argument. NO there is [no clean/good solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27368283/in-python-command-line-args-without-import) for that.

Second, I will only review the main issue, replacing `if-else` ladder with `switch`.

> You have already done the ground work for me. :)

```
Decider = [
  ('-', '0,1,2'), ('/', '0,1,2'), ('/', '2,0,1'),
  (' ', '2,0,1'), (' ', '2,1,0'), (' ', '2,0,1'),
  (' ', '2,1,0'), (' ', '0,1,2'), (' ', '0,1,2')
]

# use like
splitter(date, *Decider[i])
```

Hope this helps.